# How can I check for unique column in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to check if the entered value is a duplicated value for first line values in a file or not.

this is my code but it doesn't work

```
printf "Enter Table Name: "
read tableName
printf "Enter new Value: "
read value
for j in $(awk -F':'  '{if(NR>2) printf $1 }' $tableName); do
        if(value -eq $j); then
          printf "duplicated"
        else
          printf "not duplicated"
```

Comment: give sample inputs and expected output

Comment: `if(value -eq $j); then` => `$` missing before `value`, among other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your code through [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) and you can discover the issues for yourself.

You can use `grep` instead of looping with `awk`:

```
printf "Enter Table Name: "
read tableName
printf "Enter new Value: "
read value
if grep -qx -- "$value" <(cut -f2 -d: "$tableName"); then
  echo "duplicated"
else
  echo "not duplicated"
fi
```

It's good to validate the values entered before running `grep`:

```
printf "Enter Table Name: "
read tableName
[[ -z "$tableName" ]] && printf "No value entered for table name.\n" >&2 && exit 1
[[ ! -f "$tableName" ]] && printf "File '%s' does not exist.\n" "$tableName" >&2 && exit 1
printf "Enter new Value: "
read value
[[ -z "$value" ]] && printf "No value entered.\n" >&2 && exit 1
if grep -wq -- "$value" <(cut -f2 -d: "$tableName"); then
  echo "duplicated"
else
  echo "not duplicated"
fi
```

Comment: `grep` will find substrings too.  Do full match with `"^$value\$"`

Comment: Won't `-w` do it?

Comment: If the name doesn't contain word breaking characters, yeah.  Although at the time I wrote my comment you were not using `-w`.

Comment: the `-x` option will check against whole line... `grep -qx -- "$value"`

Comment: Thanks, used `-x` instead.